# Error deploying Ruby on Rails Application using Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am receiving the following error while deploying my rails application. What does this mean and how can I fix it? The application worked on my local machine. The only difference is that I don't have passenger on my local machine.

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started.

A source file that the application requires, is missing.

It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.

A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
cannot load such file -- URI

Exception class:
LoadError

Application root:
/home/autobrain/Autobrain

```
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `require'
1   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `block in require'
2   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 236 in `load_dependency'
3   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `require'
4   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/config/initializers/PrgRails.rb   6   in `'
5   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 245 in `load'
6   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 245 in `block in load'
7   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 236 in `load_dependency'
8   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 245 in `load'
9   /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 588 in `block (2 levels) in '
10  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 587 in `each'
11  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 587 in `block in '
12  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `instance_exec'
13  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `run'
14  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  55  in `block in run_initializers'
15  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `each'
16  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `run_initializers'
17  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb    136 in `initialize!'
18  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb   30  in `method_missing'
19  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/config/environment.rb 5   in `'
20  config.ru   3   in `require'
21  config.ru   3   in `block in
'
22  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `instance_eval'
23  /home/autobrain/Autobrain/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `initialize'
24  config.ru   1   in `new'
25  config.ru   1   in `
'
26  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 225 in `eval'
27  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 225 in `load_rack_app'
28  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 157 in `block in initialize_server'
29  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    572 in `report_app_init_status'
30  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 154 in `initialize_server'
31  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  204 in `start_synchronously'
32  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  180 in `start'
33  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 129 in `start'
34  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
35  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132 in `lookup_or_add'
36  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
37  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `block in synchronize'
38      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
39  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
40  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244 in `spawn_rack_application'
41  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137 in `spawn_application'
42  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275 in `handle_spawn_application'
43  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `server_main_loop'
44  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206 in `start_synchronously'
45  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99  in `
'
```

Comment: post /home/autobrain/Autobrain/config/environment.rb

Answer (score 0):

On Apache, try setting the environment by adding this passenger directive in your .conf file as follows:

```
RailsEnv development
```

Then restart apache!